# limit the number of suggestions AutoComplete component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've been looking at the (https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/) API for the autocomplete component but I can't seem to find a way (from my limited knowledge of javascript) to only display a certain number of options below the TextField.

I'm trying to incorporate a search function with over 7,000 data but I don't want to display all of it at once. How can I limit the options to at most 10 suggestions?

[image: comp]

Comment: Are you mapping the list from array??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done using `filterOptions` prop and `createFilterOptions` function.

```js
...
import { Autocomplete, createFilterOptions } from "@material-ui/lab";

const OPTIONS_LIMIT = 10;
const defaultFilterOptions = createFilterOptions();

const filterOptions = (options, state) => {
  return defaultFilterOptions(options, state).slice(0, OPTIONS_LIMIT);
};

function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      filterOptions={filterOptions}
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit cool-yalow-pd4i6]

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/19382)

Answer (score 2):

I started with bertida's answer but then I found out `createFilterOptions` can do it already (see https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#createfilteroptions-config-filteroptions for other interesting options)

```
const OPTIONS_LIMIT = 10;
const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
  limit: OPTIONS_LIMIT
});

function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      filterOptions={filterOptions}
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

[See codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-microservice-3dq9r?file=/index.js:223-665)

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you could use `filterOptions` as explained by @bertdida or you could directly filter `options` array in this way:

```
const ELEMENT_TO_SHOW = 10;
...
    <Autocomplete
          id="combo-box-demo"
          options={top100Films.filter((el, i) => {  // here add a filter for options
            if (i < ELEMENT_TO_SHOW) return el;
          })}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
          style={{ width: 300 }}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
          )}
        />
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-lederberg-m3qum?file=/index.js) a codesandbox example.

Comment: Note, when you do a search query on this - your query would only be applied to the first `ELEMENT_TO_SHOW` options.

Comment: @bertdida correct. Your solution basically does the same thing :)